# DatePicker showing up in multiple textfields

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdate

I am having trouble with figuring out where the code is getting mixed up.  For some reason when i click on either textFieldStartTime or textFieldEndtime they change in both as well as changing the date in textFieldDDate.

Any help is appreciated.

Extension.swift

```
import Foundation

extension NSDate{
var stringValue: String{
    return self.toString()
}

func toString() -> String {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MMM-dd"
    let str = formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    return str
}
}

extension String{
var dateValue: NSDate?{
    return self.toDate()
}

func toDate() -> NSDate? {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MMM-dd"
    if let date = formatter.dateFromString(self) {
        return date
    }else{
        // if format failed, Put some code here
        return nil // an example
    }
}
}

extension NSDate{
var starttimestringValue: String{
    return self.tostarttimeString()
}

func tostarttimeString() -> String {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    let str = formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    return str
}
}

extension String{
var starttimedateValue: NSDate?{
    return self.tostarttimeDate()
}

func tostarttimeDate() -> NSDate? {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    if let date = formatter.dateFromString(self) {
        return date
    }else{
        // if format failed, Put some code here
        return nil // an example
    }
}
}

extension NSDate{
var endtimestringValue: String{
    return self.toendtimeString()
}

func toendtimeString() -> String {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    let endstr = formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    return endstr
}
}

extension String{
var endtimedateValue: NSDate?{
    return self.toendtimeDate()
}

func toendtimeDate() -> NSDate? {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    if let date = formatter.dateFromString(self) {
        return date
    }else{
        // if format failed, Put some code here
        return nil // an example
    }
}
}
```

AddDiveLogViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AddDiveLogViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var textFieldDiveNumber: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var textFieldDiveLocation: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldDDate: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldStartTime: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldEndTime: UITextField!

var divenumber: String = ""
var divelocation: String = ""
var ddate = NSDate()
var starttime = NSDate()
var endtime = NSDate()

var datePickerView: UIDatePicker!
var timePickerView: UIDatePicker!
var endtimePickerView: UIDatePicker!

var existingItem: NSManagedObject!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (existingItem != nil) {
        textFieldDiveNumber.text = divenumber
        textFieldDiveLocation.text = divelocation
        textFieldDDate.text = ddate.stringValue
        textFieldStartTime.text = starttime.starttimestringValue
        textFieldEndTime.text = endtime.endtimestringValue

                }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // This sets up the Date Picker

    datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date


    var toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, datePickerView.frame.width, 44))
    let OKButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "OKButtonTapped:")

    toolbar.setItems([OKButton], animated: true)

    self.textFieldDDate.inputView = datePickerView
    self.textFieldDDate.inputAccessoryView = toolbar

    // This sets up the Time Picker

    timePickerView = UIDatePicker()
    timePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time


    var timetoolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, timePickerView.frame.width, 44))
    let TimeOKButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "OKButtonTapped:")

    timetoolbar.setItems([TimeOKButton], animated: true)

    self.textFieldStartTime.inputView = timePickerView
    self.textFieldStartTime.inputAccessoryView = timetoolbar

    // This sets up the End Time Picker

    endtimePickerView = UIDatePicker()
    endtimePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time


    var endtimetoolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, endtimePickerView.frame.width, 44))
    let endTimeOKButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "OKButtonTapped:")

    endtimetoolbar.setItems([endTimeOKButton], animated: true)

    self.textFieldStartTime.inputView = endtimePickerView
    self.textFieldStartTime.inputAccessoryView = endtimetoolbar





}

@IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let contxt: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Divelog", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)

    if (existingItem != nil) {
        existingItem.setValue(textFieldDiveNumber.text, forKey: "divenumber")

        existingItem.setValue(textFieldDiveLocation.text, forKey: "divelocation")
        existingItem.setValue(textFieldDDate.text.dateValue!, forKey: "ddate")
        existingItem.setValue(textFieldStartTime.text.starttimedateValue!, forKey: "starttime")
        existingItem.setValue(textFieldEndTime.text.endtimedateValue!, forKey: "endtime")

    } else {
        var newItem = Divelog(entity: en!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)

        newItem.divenumber = textFieldDiveNumber.text
        newItem.divelocation = textFieldDiveLocation.text
        newItem.ddate = textFieldDDate.text.dateValue!
        newItem.starttime = textFieldStartTime.text.starttimedateValue!
        newItem.endtime = textFieldEndTime.text.endtimedateValue!

    }



    contxt.save(nil)

    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}

@IBAction func cancelTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}

func OKButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.textFieldDDate.endEditing(true)
    self.textFieldDDate.text = datePickerView.date.stringValue

    self.textFieldStartTime.endEditing(true)
    self.textFieldStartTime.text = timePickerView.date.starttimestringValue

    self.textFieldEndTime.endEditing(true)
    self.textFieldEndTime.text = endtimePickerView.date.endtimestringValue

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand you, but when you call/click func OKButtonTapped(you are missing @IBAction!) you set textFieldDate, textFieldStartTime and textFieldEndTime

Comment: The files do save into coredata without the IBAction and I didn't need it when I just had the textFieldDDate which just saves the Date but when I add textFieldStartTime and textFieldEndTime I keep getting them mixed in with each other.    File can be found here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1z73s5c81yau2lz/AAA-14uz94AXku4DthTEaHLza?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in your code. You have set up End Time Picker with textFieldStartTime textField:

```
self.textFieldStartTime.inputView
self.textFieldStartTime.inputAccessoryView
```

So, instead of

```
// This sets up the End Time Picker

    endtimePickerView = UIDatePicker()
    endtimePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time


    var endtimetoolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, endtimePickerView.frame.width, 44))
    let endTimeOKButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK3", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "OK3ButtonTapped:")

    endtimetoolbar.setItems([endTimeOKButton], animated: true)

    self.textFieldStartTime.inputView = endtimePickerView
    self.textFieldStartTime.inputAccessoryView = endtimetoolbar
```

You should have :

```
// This sets up the End Time Picker

    endtimePickerView = UIDatePicker()
    endtimePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time


    var endtimetoolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, endtimePickerView.frame.width, 44))
    let endTimeOKButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "OKButtonTapped:")

    endtimetoolbar.setItems([endTimeOKButton], animated: true)

    self.textFieldEndTime.inputView = endtimePickerView
    self.textFieldEndTime.inputAccessoryView = endtimetoolbar
```

And it should works.

Comment: Opps, sorry I did change that before.  The problem seems to be when I call the tableViewCell and things revert back to present date and time

Answer (score 1):

Ok third answer for the third bug...

Your OKButton, TimeOKButton, endTimeOKButton trigger the same action OKButtonTapped.

In OKButtonTapped function, you initialize your date/starttime and endtime values.
Problem is that a different instance of UIDatePicker is associated with each textField inputView.

So each time you trigger OKButtonTapped, you associate textField values with each UIDatePicker i.e when you select a start time, the end time will be associate with the current day/time (and vice-versa).

My simple suggestion is to have three different actions for each Button :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (existingItem != nil) {
        textFieldDiveNumber.text = divenumber
        textFieldDiveLocation.text = divelocation
        textFieldDDate.text = ddate.stringValue
        textFieldStartTime.text = starttime.starttimestringValue
        textFieldEndTime.text = endtime.endtimestringValue

                }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // This sets up the Date Picker

    datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date


    var toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, datePickerView.frame.width, 44))
    let OKButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "OK1ButtonTapped:")

    toolbar.setItems([OKButton], animated: true)

    self.textFieldDDate.inputView = datePickerView
    self.textFieldDDate.inputAccessoryView = toolbar

    // This sets up the Time Picker

    timePickerView = UIDatePicker()
    timePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time


    var timetoolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, timePickerView.frame.width, 44))
    let TimeOKButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "OK2ButtonTapped:")

    timetoolbar.setItems([TimeOKButton], animated: true)

    self.textFieldStartTime.inputView = timePickerView
    self.textFieldStartTime.inputAccessoryView = timetoolbar

    // This sets up the End Time Picker

    endtimePickerView = UIDatePicker()
    endtimePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time


    var endtimetoolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, endtimePickerView.frame.width, 44))
    let endTimeOKButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "OK3ButtonTapped:")

    endtimetoolbar.setItems([endTimeOKButton], animated: true)

    self.textFieldEndTime.inputView = endtimePickerView
    self.textFieldEndTime.inputAccessoryView = endtimetoolbar

}
```

So you'll have three different functions :

```
func OK1ButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.textFieldDDate.endEditing(true)
    self.textFieldDDate.text = datePickerView.date.stringValue
}
func OK2ButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.textFieldStartTime.endEditing(true)
    self.textFieldStartTime.text = timePickerView.date.starttimestringValue        
}
func OK3ButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.textFieldEndTime.endEditing(true)
    self.textFieldEndTime.text = endtimePickerView.date.endtimestringValue        
}
```

It may seems redundant, but it's not because, in the end, each button is contained in different InputView, and DatePicker.

Comment: I get an error of "Definition conflicts with previous value" on both the let TimeOKButton and let endTimeOKButton code

Comment: Totally works.  Thanks for the help.  I think I will sleep now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've checked your project, and I found another bug  (the last one ? ;) ).

in DiveLogTableViewController.swift prepareForSegue function, you forgot to set starttime and endtime from CoreData.

```
    ADLVC.divenumber = selectedItem.valueForKey("divenumber") as! String
    ADLVC.ddate = selectedItem.valueForKey("ddate") as! NSDate
    ADLVC.divelocation = selectedItem.valueForKey("divelocation") as! String

    // I added this, and it works fine...

    ADLVC.starttime = selectedItem.valueForKey("starttime") as! NSDate
    ADLVC.endtime = selectedItem.valueForKey("endtime") as! NSDate
```

Try to sleep more ;)

Comment: Almost, I still get changes when I go rom the TableViewCell into the ViewController.  The dates and times keep changing.  I need to be able to add different date and start time and endgame.